# Stackposts ffmpeg error (Instagram videos)

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to post Instagram Reels via Stackposts (Ubuntu/nginx) but I am facing this error message:

`For sharing videos on Instagram, you have to install the FFmpeg library on your server and configure executables path.`

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTi1d.png)

I have ffmpeg installed but it still won't work:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 11 (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.22.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

I have tried to modify the file permissions of the library located in /bin/ffmpeg for the nginx user (www) and I have tried to move the binary to the location of the Stackposts installation.

Comment: Please explain why you're using the PHP tag in your question.

Comment: Because the framework is build with PHP and the custom error message is thrown by a ffmpeg php wrapper in the source code.

Comment: Which "framework"? There's no mention of that in your question. I think you're talking about the [Stackposts scripts](https://doc.stackposts.com/)? There will be very few people here actually using Stackposts, but you might get lucky. You could ask Stackposts itself for support.

Comment: Yes I am talking about stackposts scripts